# What's the difference between Azure D4 and D13 VM?

Tags: azure

According to the source: [Microsoft Azure Pricing](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/), D13 have double RAM (56 GB) compared to D4 (28 GB), but is cheaper. What is the difference that is not stated?

**EDIT**:

I just noticed that every region more or less have their own pricing. It is worth checking the region settings in the Pricing page to find something cheaper, if you are living between two zones. In the case of Japan West, D13 ($1.361/hr) happens to be cheaper than D4 ($1.464/hr) for some (still unanswered) reasons.

Comment: None. You've highlighted the difference.

Comment: D13 costs $1.516/hr, D4 costs $1.464/hr To me it looks like D4 is cheaper.

Comment: D4 costs $1.464/hr  and D13 costs $1.361/hr. Seems like they have a different pricing in Asia, as said by @Guarav-Mantri.

Comment: I just noticed that every region more or less have their own pricing. It is worth checking the region setting in the Pricing page to find something cheaper, if you are living between two zones.

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN web page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx) highlights the differences between Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine sizes. You will note a couple of differences between the D3 and D14 Azure VM sizes:

- The D14 role size has 56 GB of RAM whereas the D3 has 14 GB of RAM
- The D14 role size can have up to 16 attached data disks, whereas the D3 only supports 8 attached data disks
- The D14 role size temporary disk (SSD-backed on all D-Series VMs) is 400 GB whereas the D3 role size has a 200 GB temporary disk

Aside from those differences, everything else is the same with respect to technical specifications.

Comment: Just noticed something weird ... pricing for D4 is less than D13 in all US/Europe regions which makes sense considering D13 is much more powerful however it is more in Australia/Japan/Asia region.

Comment: That is pretty bizarre. Maybe check on the MVP NDA list for more details?

Comment: Already sent an email there. Let's see what they have to say. Looks like a typo to me on the pricing page.

Comment: D4 costs $1.464/hr and D13 costs $1.361/hr. Seems like they have a different pricing in Asia, as said by @Guarav-Mantri.